# Crop Image to a fixed size, on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, images, crop

What is the easiest way to crop an image into fixed 1024*768 size and select the relevant portion during cropping.

The best I was able to find is use Firefox add on to remove all it's chrome (via keyboard shortcut), and use the Alt+ Print Screen. Seems good, except it leaves the scrollbars on.

Is there a tool that highlights 1024*768 and I can move around the image for it to crop that. Its too much of a pain in the ass to use Gimp or any web tool. - But if there is a simple web app for the same, that takes the url and allows me to save back easily, I'd like to use it.

Oh, of course, I am looking for an efficient way to do it because, I am going to have to do it to many pictures.

Comment: FYI: Webapps are off topic in Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/), perhaps ? I'm not sure I get what is it that you require.

Comment: I have a lot of images, that I want to resize to 1024*768 (For including inside a presentation). Obviously I want to be able to move the image around to select the most relevant portion. What tool enables it with simplicity? :)

Comment: Shutter was exactly what I needed! I wish I could upvote you enough!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Photoshop/Gimp/... and make sure the selection box has a static size.

Comment: Photoshop is a huge download, I could avoid. I couldn't find my way thro in Gimp after 5 minutes of going thro the menu options and Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can crop any number of images to a fixed size, with a fixed start-point, using a one-line command. For example:

```
convert rose: -crop 40x30+10+10  crop.gif
```

crops the file `rose` to a 40×30 image, starting at co-ordinates 10,10 in the original.